# Shell script wont print date

Tags: bash, shell

I created this shell script it should print `The date is: 13 12 7` instead it prints `The date is`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set date var to date
date=$ (date +%y_%m_%d)

#print the date
echo "The date is: " $date
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take out the space between the $ and the rest of the command:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set date var to date
date=$(date +%y_%m_%d)

#print the date
echo "The date is: " $date
```

Answer (score 2):

You put a space between the `$` and the `(`, which prevents the command substitution you were trying to do from happening.

```
#!/bin/bash
#set date var to date
date=$(date +%y_%m_%d)

#print the date
echo "The date is: " $date
```

With the space, the line

```
date=$ (date +%y_%m_%d)
```

should produce a syntax error.